# How to sync to git repo (specific day, month, second)

Tags: git, date

I want to sync month by month to the last 12 months of commits of a repo in order to compare them.  So far I have this:

`for i in {12..1}; do`

`$(git rev-list --before "$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -$i months" +%Y-%m)-01" -n 01 HEAD); done`

This goes back monthly from the current time (so if I run it at 4:00 today it will first give me the commit closest to 4:00 12 months ago etc.).

Is there a way for git to use a constant time value, so that regardless of when I run the script it will go back monthly and report the commit closest to 12:00 or some other time?

thanks!

Comment: a.k.a. how to turn git into clearcase

Comment: For what it's worth, if you use tags to mark significant milestones (beta, stable release, whatever suits your project) then you'll have real landmarks to go back to, rather than taking the chance that exactly four months ago you were halfway through adding a feature, or worse, had just broken your build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following do what you want?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {12..1}
do
   CURRENT_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
   PAST_DATE="$(date -d "$CURRENT_DATE - $i months" "+%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00")"
   git rev-list --before "$PAST_DATE" -n 1 HEAD
done
```